# Making a calculation in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point

I need a variable `a = 6700000^2 * (a - b) (2 + sinf(a)+ s inf(b))`, where `a` and `b` are floats between -7 to 7. I need all the precision that floats can give me.

Which data type should `a` be? Is the *`sinf`* the proper function to get the best precision out of `a` and `b`? And should `a` and `b` be in radians or degrees?

---

Well I Made a mistake when I posted the expression, the correct expression is c=67000000^2*(a-b)(2+sinf(a)+sinf(b)) and my problem is with c ."a" and "b" are floats and they are passed to me as floats, they really are coordinates (latitude and longitude) so thats not my concern... My concern is when using sinf on them do I lose any precision? And which type should c be so I don't lose precision cause I'm using a long double variable d to store a sum of multiple different c variables and d is returned to me as being zero and it shouldn't (sould be about 1 or 2 )so I was gessing I was losing some precision when calculating the c parcels...I was using c as being a double...can it be that I am losing some precision when calculating c?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I doubt `(6700000)^2` will play nicely.

Comment: @Blender, that's miniscule only 13 orders of magnitude! You've got more bits on your hard-disk (probably).

Comment: @Ben: `float` only stores `7` digits. `double` only stores `15`.

Comment: @Blender That is for decimal floating points, binary floating points can carry 8 digits in some circumstances. Also, since floating points make use of scientific notation, ultimately you can have numbers much larger than those, but they will not be precisely represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `float`,  you should use a `double` if you want no worries in regards to memory.  Remember to then change `sinf()` to `sin()` and use radians.

Comment: `long double` and `double` are the same in iOS (both are IEEE-754 binary-64).

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell you whether `float` is good enough for your application.  If you need more precision, use `double`, and then use `sin()` instead of `sinf()`.

The standard trig functions take angles in radians, as you'll discover if you read the [relevant documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sin.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best precision without rolling your own types, you should use `double` rather than `float`.  In that case, you can just use [`sin(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sin.3.html).  According to the [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sin.3.html), you should pass the argument in radians.